# moving wordpress mu to another domain - sql statements

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm assuming these instructions are for "normal" wordpress... will this work with wpmu or do i need to modify this? Is there anything i should watch for?

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/

Answer (score 0):

See [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) and [WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

The biggest issue you face is changing URLs in the database; and you will need to change these URLs in each of the individual databases that Multisite installs uses. Check out the find/replace tool linked above; it correctly deserializes/serializes data in the database. If you change URLs in a text database dump, or with SQL queries as in the link you listed in your question, you risk breaking data, such as theme options and widget settings.

*1/09/2016 Note: WordPress MU doesn't exist anymore. MU was rolled into WordPress core in version 3.0.*

Comment: True, but this is a 4 year old answer; and WordPress MU doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: This was just an automatic comment from review process in the Low Quality Posts queue.